# Optimize SQL query in foreach()

Tags: php, android, foreach

I have an Android App, it is a virtual store.

In this App I made a query to fill a `list --> category --> subcategory --> products`. The problem here is the optimisation in the `foreach`.

How can  optimize the foreach?

```
Shop::setIdShop(Tools::getValue('boutique'));
$cntxt =  Context::getContext();
$cntxt->shop = new Shop(Tools::getValue('boutique'));

$categorie = New Category(Tools::getValue('id_category')); 

   $result_product_count = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('
     SELECT COUNT(p.`id_product`) as totalProducts
     FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p , `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_shop` ps
     WHERE p.`active` = 1
     AND p.`id_product` = ps.`id_product`
     AND ps.`id_shop` = '.$cntxt->shop->id);
     $count = $result_product_count[0]['totalProducts'];



$promos = Product::getPricesDrop($id_lang = 1, $page_number = 0, $nb_products = $count, $count = false,
$order_by = null, $order_way = null, $beginning = false, $ending = false,  $context = $cntxt);

$products = $categorie->getProducts($context->language->id,0,$result_product_count[0]['totalProducts'] , null ,null , false , $active = true, $random = false, $random_number_products = 1, $check_access = true, $context = $cntxt);

$sql_gestion_stock = 'SELECT value FROM `ps_configuration` WHERE name="PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT" AND id_shop="'.$cntxt->shop->id.'"';
$result_gestion_stock = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql_gestion_stock);

$sql_order_stock = 'SELECT value FROM `ps_configuration` WHERE name="PS_ORDER_OUT_OF_STOCK" AND id_shop="'.$cntxt->shop->id.'"';
$result_order_stock = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql_order_stock);

$resultat = array();
$row = array();


foreach($products as $p)
{
    $prod = new Product($p['id_product']);

    $order_out_of_stock = Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_OUT_OF_STOCK','','',$cntxt->shop->id);
    $stock_management = Configuration::get('PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT','','',$cntxt->shop->id);
    $sql_stock = 'SELECT out_of_stock FROM ' ._DB_PREFIX_. 'stock_available WHERE id_product="'.$p['id_product'].'" AND id_shop="'.Tools::getValue('boutique').'"';
    $out_of_stock = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql_stock);
    $stock_dispo = $out_of_stock[0]['out_of_stock'];

    if( $stock_management == 0 ){
        $qty = 9999;
        $out_of_stock_mobile = 1;
    }
    else{
        if($stock_dispo == 0){
            $qty = $prod->getRealQuantity($p['id_product'],0,0,Tools::getValue("boutique"));
            $out_of_stock_mobile = 0;
        }
        elseif( $stock_dispo == 1 ){
            $qty = 9999;
            $out_of_stock_mobile = 1;
        }
        elseif( $stock_dispo == 2 ){
            if($order_out_of_stock == 1){
                $qty = 9999;
                $out_of_stock_mobile = 1;
            }
            else{
                $qty = $prod->getRealQuantity($p['id_product'],0,0,Tools::getValue("boutique"));
                $out_of_stock_mobile = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    $link = New Link();
    $img='';
    $imgLink = '';
    if (count($prod->getImages($cntxt->language->id ,$context = $cntxt ))>0) {
    $imgCover = Product::getCover($prod->id, $context = $cntxt);
    $imgLink = $link->getImageLink($prod->link_rewrite[1] , $imgCover["id_image"] , 'medium_default');
    $imgLink = 'http://'.$imgLink; 
    $largeImgLink = $link->getImageLink($prod->link_rewrite[1] , $imgCover["id_image"] , 'large_default');
    $largeImgLink = 'http://'.$largeImgLink; 
    }
    $row['hasSold']= 0; 
    if (count(promos)>0) {
        foreach($promos as $promo)
        {

            if ($promo['id_product'] == $p['id_product']) {
            $rowProd = array('id_product' => $p['id_product'],'out_of_stock' => $prod->out_of_stock);
            $productProp = $prod->getProductProperties($id_lang = 1 , $rowProd , $context = $cntxt );
            $now = time();
            $date1 = strtotime($productProp["specific_prices"]["to"]);
            $diff = abs($date1 - $now);
             $tmp = $diff;
             $retour = array();
                $retour['second'] = $tmp % 60;

                $tmp = floor( ($tmp - $retour['second']) /60 );
                $retour['minute'] = $tmp % 60;

                $tmp = floor( ($tmp - $retour['minute'])/60 );
                $retour['hour'] = $tmp % 24;

                $tmp = floor( ($tmp - $retour['hour'])  /24 );
                $retour['day'] = $tmp;
            $row['hasSold']= 1; 
            $row['temps_restant']= $retour['day'].'j '.$retour['hour'].':'.$retour['minute'].':'.$retour['second'];
            }

        }
    }


    $row['image']= $imgLink; 
    $row['titre']=$prod->name["1"];
    $row['description']=strip_tags($prod->description["1"]);
    $row['largeImage']= $largeImgLink; 
    $images = $prod->getImages((int)$cntxt->language->id);
    $imagesmeduim=array();
    $imageslarge=array();
    $j=0;
    foreach($images as $i)
    {
        if (!$i['cover'])
        {
        $imgLink_list = $link->getImageLink($prod->link_rewrite[1] , $i["id_image"] , 'medium_default');
        $largeImgLink_list = $link->getImageLink($prod->link_rewrite[1] , $i["id_image"] , 'large_default');
        $imagesmeduim[$j]=$imgLink_list;
        $imageslarge[$j]=$largeImgLink_list;
        $j++;
        }
    }


    $row['qty']= $qty;
    $row['out_of_stock'] = $out_of_stock_mobile;
    $row['id_product']=$p['id_product'];
    $row['sous_titre']=strip_tags($prod->description_short["1"]);
    $row['prix_promotion']= (string)$prod->getPrice(true,NULL,2);
    $row['prix_orig']= Tools::ps_round((string)$prod->getPriceWithoutReduct(), 2);
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == NULL) {
            $row[$key]='';
        }
    }
    $row['images_meduim']= $imagesmeduim;       
    $row['images_large']= $imageslarge; 
    $resultat[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($resultat);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to not use two table in the from statement in your SQL query and use the inner join because it's faster like

```
SELECT COUNT(p.`id_product`) as totalProducts
   FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p 
   inner join `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_shop` ps
   on p.`id_product` = ps.`id_product`
   WHERE p.`active` = 1
   AND ps.`id_shop` = '.$cntxt->shop->id);
```

and I don't understand why you use this

```
$order_out_of_stock = Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_OUT_OF_STOCK','','',$cntxt->shop->id);
$stock_management = Configuration::get('PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT','','',$cntxt->shop->id);
```

in the foreach, it will do all time the same so maybe you sould do it out of the foreach ?

----EDIT----

So maybe you can do some other thing like don't use a foreach for your promo

like

```
if(isset($promo[$p['id_product']])
{
    $rowProd = array('i.....
```

instead of

```
if (count(promos)>0) {
    foreach($promos as $promo)
{ 
   if ($promo['id_product'] == $p['id_product']) {
```

but if you really get a lot of data and action i'm not sure the server velocity change anythink .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I update my code, sorry for that.

Comment: I have 34 categories and 1500 products.

Normally I fill the list in 32 segs. with the inner join 28 segs.

Is the problem with the foreach or is problem with the server velocity?

Thanks again

Comment: No, but the app will be in French, also I speak the language.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer

Still the same time, or maybe is normal by the quantity of products?

Comment: i think that the number of product isn't the problem. because i have some query with more like 40000 row of 20 filed and my page take less of 5 sec to be load. so it's probably more because your foreach do too much action or you get some problem in an action who take a lot of time or just your browser who take a lot of time to display what you want. when you calculate the time it's when the php script ending or when the page is display ?

Comment: So I have a big problem with the time

and is the time to display in the list of mobile, maybe is the method to get and put in the list?

Comment: i'm sorry i wasn't here this week end, or it's maybe the time to display it, maybe you should look the time that take the script without display. if you find this too long it's indeed either the build of your data or your list, otherwise it's the time to display and you have to find an other way to display it